# Return filtered Excel table with headers

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using code by Ron de Bruin to e-mail Excel Table with Outlook.

I'm getting the data range but missing the headers.

I do some filtering which can result in a blank range and this should not be sent (current code facilitates it nicely with `If rng Is Nothing Then`)

*edit: proposing a potential direction*

Could I define a new range `Range1` which includes Table1 + its header?
Tested it and the code runs + is including the header, however `Range1` is never empty now, even if filtering provides 0 rows.

```
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Range1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

The header will now provide one row and `rng` is never `Nothing`. Can this code be adjusted to exit with one visible row, instead of `Nothing`?

```vb
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
    'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
    'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    
    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    'Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If rng Is Nothing Then
    '    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
    '           vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "test@mail.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .HTMLBody = "HARDCODED HEADER?" & RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
    
    
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
    
    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
    
    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    
    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
          SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
          Filename:=TempFile, _
          Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
          Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
          HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With
    
    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")
    
    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
    
    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile
    
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using this

```
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

replace it with

```
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Range
```

The 1st one you used only copy the data of the table. The 2nd code I put will get the whole range of the table header + the data on the table

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately that doesn't really work for me as expected. It will email the entire table, however there will be some filtering and I only want to email the filtered out data (which xCellTypeVisible does fine).

ListObjects("Table1").Range WILL include the header though, but also a lot of rows that are actually filtered out.

I'd want to email only header + result of the filtered rows (and not send out a plain header in case filtering will not result in any matches).